# Multithreaded winsock server not accepting clients c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock

So I have a winsock application in which the computer tries to accept a client, and then starts a new thread with the a pointer to the class object with client info which it copies and then deletes with the delete keyword. 
The backbone is copied but the beginning of the OOP-structure is my work and the current implementation seems to be giving me some issues. 
I noticed the socket might not copy in the correct format, but have no idea on how to fix this. As the client tries to connect it throws me the error message of that the server refused the connection. Anyway, here is the code of the server.

**UPDATE:**
It's working.

```
// main.h
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>


#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib" )

class clientData{
private:
    SOCKET clientSocket;
    std::string name;

public:
    clientData(SOCKET &clientSock, const char *tName);

    clientData(clientData *cliDat);

    ~clientData();

    inline SOCKET *getClientSocket(){
        return &clientSocket;
    }

    inline std::string *getName(){
        return &name;
    }

};
```

And here is the main cpp file

```
// main.cpp
#include "main.h"



unsigned int __stdcall  ServClient(void *data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    SOCKET sock, client[10];

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(13337);
    addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);//2.2 

    if (iResult)
    {
        printf("WSA startup failed");
        return 0;
    }


    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Invalid socket");
        return 0;
    }
    int addrlen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    iResult = bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    if (iResult)
    {

        printf("bind failed %u", GetLastError());

        return 0;
    }

    iResult = listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);

    if (iResult)
    {

        printf("iResult failed %u", GetLastError());

        return 0;
    }

    int iterationCount = 0;
    while ((iterationCount < 10 && 
        (client[iterationCount] = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)) != SOCKET_ERROR))
    {
        if (client[iterationCount] == INVALID_SOCKET){
            printf("invalid client socket",GetLastError());
            continue;
        }   

        ++iterationCount;
        char tempName[100] = { '\0' };
        sprintf_s(tempName, sizeof(tempName), "Client %u", iterationCount);
        clientData *tempCLdata = new clientData(client[iterationCount - 1], tempName);
        _beginthreadex(0, 0, ServClient, (void*)tempCLdata, 0, 0);
        tempCLdata = nullptr;
    }


    return 0;
}

unsigned int __stdcall ServClient(void *data)
{
    clientData cliDat((clientData*)data);
    delete (clientData*)data;
    printf("Client connected\n");

    int recvLen = 1;
    char chunk[1024] = { '\0' };
    while ((recvLen = recv(*cliDat.getClientSocket(), chunk, 1024, 0)) > 0){
        printf("%.*s", recvLen, chunk);
    }
    if (recvLen == -1)
        perror("Socket recv() problem..\n");
    else
        printf("End of data on socket, closing..\n");

    closesocket(*cliDat.getClientSocket());

    return 0;
}



clientData::clientData(SOCKET &clientSock, const char *tName){
    clientSocket = clientSock;
    name.assign(tName);
}

clientData::clientData(clientData *cliDat){

    SOCKET *clientSocketPtr = cliDat->getClientSocket();
    clientSocket = *clientSocketPtr;
    name.assign(cliDat->getName()->c_str());
}

clientData::~clientData(){
}
```

Also here is the relevant bit of client code, as requested.

```
    char buffer[1023] = { '\0' };
    int heartbeatCount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "Heartbeat %d", heartbeatCount + 1);
        send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1, 0);
        ++heartbeatCount;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");  <-- are you intentionally only binding to the loopback device?  Because by doing that you are indicating that you only want to receive connections from clients running on the same computer.  If you want to allow connections from clients running on other computers as well, you should set this field to INADDR_ANY instead.

Comment: Also your while loop is treating a zero-value returned from accept() as an error; according the man page accept() returns -1 on an error, and 0 could be a valid socket fd.

Comment: Right now they are running on the same computer, though in the future I will maybe implement a client on my ubuntu laptop if it's not too hard, so this is valuable info. The noobie mistakes are probably many. Thanks Jeremy.

Comment: 'Connection refused' means there was nothing listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. Error messages are printed, not thrown. If you reach the maximum iteration count, you aren't closing the accepted socket, so you are leaking FDs. You can't write correct networking code without storing the result of `recv()` into a variable and testing it at least twice and using it to delimit whatever you do with the buffer if it was positive. Your message saying 'no message received' will be incorrect in most cases.

Comment: Corrected the loop a bit. Going to work on the `recv()` bit. Thanks for the info so far.

Comment: You need to post the relevant client code.

Comment: Also, recving 1024 bytes into a 1024 byte buffer may use all the buffer, making the cargo-cult buffer zero initialization pointless and  and a subsequent UB attempt to printf("%...) a char array that is not null-terminated.

Comment: Right Martin, thanks for pointing that out. Edited to only recv 1023 bytes and edited in the client code aswell.

Comment: 'Sleep(1000); - why?

Comment: I don't remember why I put it in there. Removed.

Comment: The correct form of a receive loop is `while ((len = recv(...)) > 0)`, then at its end you test for `len == -1` and call `perror()` etc. Otherwise the loop terminated normally with a peer disconnect. Note the parentheses, which aren't correct in yours. The way you have it, it is impossible to tell what happened. And your `printf()` is not 'as advised by EJP' at all. I gave no such advice. It should be `printf("%.*s", recvLen, chunk);` And `"no message received"` is still wrong unless the loop never iterated at all, which you aren't testing for. A correct message would be 'end of stream'.

Comment: Okay, sorry EJP. Will remove you from the comment. Thanks dude. I need to read up more on the printf syntax I guess edit: or just c++ in general

Comment: You still have the parentheses wrong. That's why it's failing. And no test for -1 after the loop.

Comment: As I debug it the `cliDat.clientSocket == 1`. There must be something wrong with the way I'm constructing the object from the pointer.

Comment: You have the same parentheses problem in the `accept()` line.

Comment: Aaand presto. It works for now. Thanks. Those are mistakes I would probably not notice..

Comment: You need to convince yourself why it works now. The precedence of > is higher than =, so you were evaluating a comparison to zero and assigning the result, 0 or 1, to the socket.

Comment: Right, I understand. And I now know that I need to tread warily around longer statements with lots of parenthesises(?).

Comment: Not at all. You just need to understand them. It's not hard. A few things left over: see my last edit.

Comment: Yeah thanks. However, doesn't end of data-stream on the socket mean that no more data was recieved on the socket?